# JS hide html content when mouse leave the content area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an element which will appear after I click a button. What i want now is to hide the element when my mouse pointer leave the element. How is that possible? Thanks

JS script :

```
          $(document).ready(function() {

          $('.hide').hide();



          $('.button').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('div').find('.hide').toggle(400);
            return false;           
          });
```

HTML code :

```
<a class="button" >More</a>

<div class="hide" ><img src="images/icon.png" /></div>
//I want this div hide element to hide after my mouse pointer leave this div area
```

Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("div.hide").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".hide").hide();
});
```

For showing again the div contents you can use mouseenter() like:

```
$("div.hide").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".hide").show();
});
```

OR you can also do like: (For Toggle use)

```
$("div.hide").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".hide").hide();
}).mouseenter(function(){
    $(".hide").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `mouseout` event?

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Although `mouseout` can be used, this event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. See the discussion for [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) for a useful alternative.